# wp_signon gives error insufficient_permissions

Tags: login, permissions, web-services

This seems odd to me because if you're signing on a user you shouldn't already be signed in... therefore your permissions shouldn't matter.

It may be a bit of an odd way of going about it, so that could be causing the issue. Here's the code:

```
function login( $user_name, $password ) {
    $creds = array();
    $creds['user_login'] = $user_name;
    $creds['user_password'] = $password;
    $creds['remember'] = false;

    $user = wp_signon( $creds, true );

    if( is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
        $result = $user;
    }
    else {
        /* do some other stuff */
    }

    return $result;
}
```

This is found on a separate page used for web services... this page loads the proper WordPress functions with:

```
require_once('../../../../../wp-load.php');
```

And is posted to via jQuery from the front end.

Worth noting that other WP functions such as interaction with `global $wpdb` works in this file.

Comment: What is the exact error WordPress is giving you when you use this?

Comment: fail insufficient_permissions: Current user does not have the permissions to execute that function

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding the Question, but the sample code works for me, if run as an autonomous PHP file. Are you getting this error in jQuery? Because I only found 3 occurrences for "insufficient" in WordPress core... Snapshot: http://cl.ly/I4FS

Comment: As @brasofilo said, there is no such error in the WordPress core. Exactly what happens when you run this code and exactly what is the real error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

A [quick Google on that error](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22Current%20user%20does%20not%20have%20the%20permissions%20to%20execute%20that%20function%22) garners two results: this question, and an indexed error response from a script named `venue_admin_api.php`.

Is that your website? Or are you using the same library?

Regardless, somewhere in your codebase (ignoring WP core), that error exists - find it, & post the surrounding code, otherwise I can't see how we can help any further!